# Is it safe to delete an accidental copy of root folder?

Tags: root-filesystem, delete

I accidentally copied my root folder to my local folder using the command `cp -r /`. Several folders like */boot* and */opt* were copied.

Is it safe to delete these folders from my local directory using something like `rm -r boot`?

Comment: What do you mean with **local** folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The files are mere copies, you will not face problems. Deletion of system-critical files would need administrative permissions.